# Making a JOIN WHERE key IN(SELECT key FROM...) using Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Im a noob in Sequelize.js and somewhat less in Angular but must solve a problem in which I want to use a subquery as a condition of a JOIN. I paste some examples below because code says more then words.

**SQL**

```sql
INNER JOIN table ON table.key IN(SELECT current_key FROM historysnake WHERE original_key IN(
       SELECT original_key FROM historysnake WHERE current_key = table.key)
AND historysnake.model = 'tablename')
```

The question is: How can I put above query into a Sequelize object? Something like:

**Sequelize.js**

```
var foo = sequelize.define('foo', {...}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            foo.hasMany(...)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with a self join association, such as `HistorySnake.hasOne(HistorySnake, ....);` which you would include in the `table.findAll`.  But, your SQL is confusing:  it looks like the 2nd pass at historySnake will always match the 1st pass.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I shall elaborate somewhat more. I'm developing an application in which caregivers can register stuff about patients. If someone registers an event and later wants te edit the registration the original registration gets historized and a new one is created. All those registrations are linked together via the Historysnake with an current_key, previous_key and original_key. Hence the query to get the 'snake'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's an example, which assumes that PK of PatientEvents is the original_key on all the history rows:

```
PatientEvents.hasMany(HistorySnake, {foreignKey : 'original_key'});

PatientEvents.findAll({
   include: [{
       model: HistorySnake,
       required : true,      // true = INNER JOIN but you might need outer join to see events with no history
       where : { modelName : 'PatientEvents' }  // as needed
       }],
   where: { patient_name : 'xyz' }  // as needed
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'm not really sure if @KenOn10's answer would've worked. I'm too much of a noob on this subject for that but thanks for the answer anyway.

I ended up specifying my own 'on' clause like this.

```
models.Aim.find({
    include: [{
        model: models.ObjectiveReport,
        required: false,
        where: ['ObjectiveReports.report_entrydate >= ?', show_date],
            on: {
                aim_id: sequelize.literal('aim.aim_id IN(SELECT current_key FROM historysnake WHERE original_key IN(SELECT original_key FROM historysnake WHERE current_key = aim.aim_id) AND historysnake.model = "aim")')
            })
...
```